# Use of "it" to refer to virtual things

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns

I work as a software developer. At times I have to talk about virtual, non-tangible things, like images for a website etc. In these cases, the pronoun that I use is *it*. E.g.

> *Colleague:* "Add the image that I mailed."
>   *Me:* "Didn't get **it** yet!"

I feel that using *it* in this case isn't right as the image is a virtual thing that we cannot touch and hence there should be some other pronoun in this place.

Comment: What on Earth makes you think *it* has to be a tangible thing? (Or that it has to be a thing at all, for that matter — have you never noticed that *it* is dark outside, or that *it* is raining, or how hard *it* is to be a woman sometimes?) And what other pronouns are you considering? And why would it be okay to use a full-fledged *noun* for that thing ("image"), if you can't even use a measly non-descript pronoun?

Comment: No other noun only `it` hence is it right to use it in this case. Not on earth because softwares aren't the part of the planet :D

Comment: You might be interested in a related site: [ell.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronoun *it* can have as its antecedent any single inanimate object. It (see?) doesn’t have to be tangible. Nouns can be broadly classed as concrete nouns or abstract nouns, and *it* can refer to even the most abstract concepts.

Comment: he or she can't be ever used in abstract concepts then it. Does it mean this ?

Comment: Or no concept, for that matter. When you need a dummy to please the grammar rules, *it* happily chips in. **It** is not necessary to have an antecedent.